# Spring Social prepoplating local registeration form with values from provider

Tags: spring, spring-social

I'm trying to pre-populate my local registration with Linkedin Callback. I am getting a NullPointer Exception on the "Email" field when I attempt to register.

It is possible that Email Address Field is not accessible with Linkedin but the Class UserProfile (used to populate fields) Docs say otherwise - "model provides access to those common fields in an uniform way".

It works with Facebook. When the Authentication process is triggered with a click on "Sign in with Facebook" Button, I am redirected back to the local site (after authentication) with the local signup form pre-populated with name and email.

This does not work for LinkedIn or Twitter, both throw NullPointer Exception.  I would like settings for both LinkedIn and Twitter.

Here is my form

Linkedin

```
<form name="linkedin_signin" id="linkedin_signin" action="${linkedin_uri}" method="POST">
    <input type="image" src="${linkedin_img}" />
</form>
```

Twitter

```
<form:form id="twitter_signin" action="${twitter_uri}" method="POST">
<input type="image" src="${twitter_img}" />
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must request **r_emailaddress** permission when authorizing your application for LinkedIn.

```
<form name="linkedin_signin" id="linkedin_signin" action="${linkedin_uri}" method="POST">
    <input type="image" src="${linkedin_img}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="r_emailaddress" />
</form>
```

- Permissions for LinkedIn: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting
- Permissions for Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions

It looks like you can't do it with twitter https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4019

Comment: It looks like you can't do it with twitter https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4019

Comment: Are you sure that application account records were removed from Linkedin side before test? Info about requested email address permission was shown during signin like on this image https://developer.linkedin.com/sites/default/files/gp-dialog.png ?

Comment: I dont see the "requested email address permission"

Comment: <form:form name="linkedinin_signin" id="linkedin_signin" action="${linkedin_uri}" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress" />
  <input type="image" src="${linkedin_img}" />
 </form:form>

Comment: I think your forms processed by org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController or org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController. Make brekepoints and check that scope parameter was sended correctly to LinkedIn.

Comment: The scope parameter seems to work for Facebook so I am not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: LinkedIn is an OAuth 1.0a provider, but the scope parameter is not standard in OAuth 1.0a (it is standard in OAuth 2). By offering a scope parameter, LinkedIn has a non-standard implementation of OAuth 1.0a and, up until very recently, Spring Social didn't support any non-standard parameters when fetching a request token or during authorization. The latest 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT builds of Spring Social *do* support non-standard parameters, including LinkedIn's scope parameter. The HTML in the original answer should work now. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SOCIAL-349 for details.

Comment: Also note that the support for non-standard parameter is very new, so you can only get it in snapshot builds. Soon (probably early next week, barring any surprises) I'll push a new 1.1.0.M2 release that will include this.